# counting match product ssrs 2005

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a table that produces the following
Im trying to get the percent of the recorded Type that have damage of 5

```
Food dish           Type    Damaged  X Y
Italian soup        A       D
                    B       D
                    D       D
                    E       10
                    F       4
                    C       5
                    B       5
                    E       10
```

I have an expression that can count number of times Damage displays 5 but I've been struggling with getting it to count the matched Type 
my formula is in X =(sum(iif(Fields!Damaged.Value ="5",1,0)))*2
I have tried this Y =count(Fields!Type.value=(Switch(Fields!Damaged.Value ="5",Fields!Type.Value))) but all i get with this is the count of everything in Type 
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance, Tariq

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They aren't the same thing.

Comment: Try this Y = count(Fields!Type.value=(Switch(Fields!Damaged.Value ="5",Fields!Type.Value, 1=1, Nothing)))

Comment: I tried that but it still gives me the count for all items